# How to call a javascript function from .js file in a Drupal module file

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm trying to modify an existing module to insert collapsible div.
my javascript functions are in the file 'my_module.js' and look like that :

```
my_module.js

function myFunction1(param){
...
}

function myFunction2(paramA, paramB){
...
}
```

I added my_module.js  in module file using  drupal_add_js and then I don’t know what to do next!

```
<?php

    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/my_module.js');
    // -----> I want to call myFunction2 here !!
?>
```

The website has Drupal core 6.24.

thx

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Drupal. If you're in an HTML file that gets displayed, just escape out of the PHP and call your JS as you normally would (or write it out to the page). If you're in PHP, you can't call JS like that - it has to get interpreted in a JS engine, of which PHP is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just continue with my_module.js as normal javascript file. You can try to insert div by using JQuery.

```
$("#foo").append("<div id='my_collapsible'>hello world</div>")
```

And by JQuery attach to #my_collapsible some actions you want (make it collapsible).

Answer (score 0):

That method should actually work.

Have you:

- Checked the file paths are correct
- Checked in firebug/webkit inspector that the JS file is being loaded?